# Shortcut to nested type in C++ class

Tags: c++, enums

In a generated class I have an anonymous enum with many members, some with long names, like this:

```
class ContainerClass {
public:
  enum { Enum1, EnumWithLongName2 ...};
};
```

This is fine to express that these enums solely belong to that class. At times however I have a large list of these enums (e.g. in result lists for unit tests), which get very large when I have to qualify each enum with the class' name. Is there a way to add a shortcut in such cases so that I can omit the class name?

I looked at [C++'s type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), but that doesn't seem to help here. Other ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can export all the values of your anonymous enum outside the class. Maybe you can generate this class with a enum name? You could also alias the `ContainerClass` to something shorter when you need it so you would only have, e.g. `CC::Enum1` instead of `ContainerClass::Enum1` (not as short as `Enum1` thought).

Comment: True, aliasing the container class would help somewhat.

Comment: @Holt: The lack of a name is no real issue; `decltype(Enum1)` uniquely identifies the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's one : a [derived class](http://ideone.com/4RZ9O9) inherits the enum names and can use them without further qualification.

So, create a helper class which inherits from `ContainerClass` to define the list. However, the helper class isn't intended to be instantiated (You wouldn't want to crate another `ContainerClass` base subobject) so define the list as a `static` member:

```
class enumList : public ContainerClass {
        enumList() = delete;
    public:
        static decltype(Enum1) list[2] = { Enum1, EnumWithLongName2 };
};
```